# ::after pseudo-element width is different of content

Tags: css, sass

I am creating a horizontal menu with navigation tabs. When these tabs float left in small devices, to pretend that they look more real I add a ::after pseudo-element for extend their height.

[image: Navigation tab]

But the li width is 2px bigger than li::after width.

sass without :hover, :focus and other tags style looks like this:

```
.nav-tabs {
   & > li {
      border: 1px solid $gray-light;
      border-bottom-color: white;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      padding: 0 $margin-default;

      &::after {
         display: block;
         position:absolute;
         height:200px;
         width: 100%;
         z-index: -2;
         left: 0;
         border-left: 1px solid $border-color;
         border-right: 1px solid $border-color;
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: Thanks :) . So outline property helps me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolute positioning width does not take account of borders...that's the issue.

So you will have to adjust accordingly

`calc` is a good option here.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  border-width: 0 10px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  /* 2 x 10px */
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  background: pink;
  left: -10px;
  /* 1x border-width */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have used `position: absolute;` to  `&::after`, there is no parent which has  `position: relative;` Apply `position: relative` to `.nav-tabs`

```
.nav-tabs {
   position: relative;
      & > li {
         /* Your styles */
      }
      &::after {
       /* Your styles */
     }
}
```

Try this, this will really help you.